# Saving file to a directory when porgram installed on another computer.

Tags: c#, setup-project

I created a setup project with installshield to install my program on other computers. I have to save an image to use later. But the image is not being saved on the directory that i created. Here is the line:

```
image.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\config\\Choosen.bmp");
```

(Application.StartupPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\PT\My Product Name). After this line an image has to be in the directory but there is nothing.

and the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\PT\My Product Name\data\config exists.
The code work when i execute it from the solution project, but when i install it to another computer it doesn't work. I am sure somebody knows the answer :)

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use logging to find out real run-time value for Application.StartupPath as well as any exceptions thrown by target code. I hope it will lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite likely that you don't have permission to edit files at that path.

You're better off saving any data in the user's application data folder

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

or using a resource file: [MSDN - Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @cagri You're welcome. If this answer worked for you, the way we say thanks on Stack Overflow is by marking the answer as accepted (by clicking the tick (✓) next to this post) - you'll get some reputation points for doing so too!